# How do I create this CMYK effect in Photoshop?

Tags: cmyk, channel

I assume there’s some channel separation but I can’t get an image that’s the same result.

[image]

Comment: It's not channels.. the colors don't indicate channel overlapping. It's simply a collection of randomly colored shapes.

Comment: Welcome on GD.SE, Rav. In your example the shape was moved before spraying each color, in order to obtain the effect, like a big [misregistration](http://the-print-guide.blogspot.com/search/label/Registration). Search for [halftone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halftone) and see this [Photoshop tutorial](https://creativepro.com/how-to-make-amazing-halftone-effects-with-photoshop/) which can help you.

Comment: So to outline it a bit more: you should have the character in 3 different layers, possibly smart objects. Give each layer different color fills and blend mode: Linear Dodge (Add). If you add color fills with layer style: `Color Overlay`, you'll have to set layer fill to 0% and set the blend mode in the `Color Overlay` layer style instead of the whole layer.

Comment: Thank you, all! What a great community here! Definitely enough information to get a similar effect!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your image was probably created with a process like the one suggested by Scott.

In Gimp (sorry, I don't have Photoshop, but the process is the same), you can obtain a similar effect starting from three identical shapes filled respectively with Yellow, Magenta and Cyan, e.g.:

[image: Yellow Shape]

If you set the layer mode of the two upper layers on Subtract (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMY_color_model) for a reference) and move the layers as you like, your result is something like this:

[image: Merged layer]

Adding a white background and a canvas you obtain:

[image: Merged layers with bg and canvas]

Maybe a little blur can also help:

[image: Blurred image]

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks!

Comment: Take the time to make your attempts, Rav, and if the answer is satisfactory, mark it as correct.